# Unexpected "expression is always true" from Resharper on null check

Tags: c#, resharper

Consider the following program,

```
class Foo
{
    public string Score { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static Foo GetFoo(int x) => x < 0 ? null : new Foo {Score = x > 100 ? $"{x}": "^"};

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");

        var foo = GetFoo(-2);

        switch (foo?.Score)
        {
            case string s when int.TryParse(s, out _):
                Console.WriteLine("Score exists");
                break;
            case null:
                break;
        }

        if (!int.TryParse(foo?.Score, out _))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(foo.Score);
        }
    }
}
```

When executed, a `NullReferenceException` is thrown on `Console.WriteLine(foo.Score)`, because `foo` is null.

When the `if` is modified to

```
if (foo != null && !int.TryParse(foo?.Score, out _))
```

ReSharper 2018.2.3 reports that `foo != null` is always true. Am I missing something here or is this a defect in ReSharper?

--

Note: That switch in the middle has already been re-factored to something more sensible.

Comment: It's a redundant check because the subsequent `!int.TryParse(foo?.Score, out _)` covers the `null` check with the null propagating operator.

Comment: i tried your code and got `foo == null`

Comment: What if you try `if(foo != null && !int.TryParse(foo.Score, out _))`?  Since you already know `foo` isn't `null` when you try to parse `Score`.

Comment: @spender That was my first thought - omitting the null check throws an NRE.

Comment: Repros exactly on Resharper 2017.3.1.  Foo shows up always null, and there's a NRE on the WriteLine call.  Putting in the null-check fixes the code, but generates the Resharper "always true" warning, even though foo is null and `foo != null` is false.  Seems like a Resharper bug to me.  It looks like the solution is a `// ReSharper disable once ConditionIsAlwaysTrueOrFalse` annotation. By the way, thanks for the drop-in code repro!

Comment: Does the Resharper warning go away if you change `GetFoo(-2)` to something that doesn't produce `null`?

Comment: You've found a case where R# says that the thing definitely is not null when it definitely is null, so by definition that's a bug in R#. Consider reporting the bug.